# UIScrollView/UITableView set ContentOffset kills inertia/scroll?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

In a UITableView, because I am adding row on top of other row and I don't want the user to notice anything. I am setting the ContentOffset of the scroll with animation:NO.
Everything works perfectly, I think my calculations are right.

However, when I set the ContentOffset while the table is scrolling, it looks like it stopped. 
Is setting the content offset killing the inertia/scrolling?
Or am I dreaming?

Is there a way to save the current scrolling parameters and re-applying them after setContentOffset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` extends `UIScrollView`. You can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods , add your actions in a queue and when the `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;` gets called , perform those actions. This would enable you to only change the offset when the tableView is not scrolling.